# render code to page using JSX whilst preserving line breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, render, jsx

I am trying to use a field that will contain a load of code that contains line breaks and tabs. I want it to render and retain the tabs and line breaks.

Basically I want it to look like the code is formatted in stack overflow when I output it. When I use string literals it doesn't retain the tabs and line breaks.

Below is my code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import FunctionalContext from '../../context/functional/functionalContext';


const FunctionalComponent = () => {
  const functionalContext = useContext(FunctionalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Classes</h1>
      <h2>Classes</h2>
      <code>{`
          import React from 'react'
        constructor() {
          super()
      `}
      </code>



    </div>
  )
}

export default FunctionalComponent
```

Comment: you are correct and there is an error there but it still works and that is not the cuase of the problem - I will update the code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code` element isn't preformatted by default. You can either apply one of the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) styles to it, or put it in a [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element.

I think you'll struggle with getting the tabs rendered in a useful way, though. You may want to expand them out to whatever tab stops were being used by the author before outputting instead.

Example of using `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const code =
`
import React from 'react';

class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Classes</h1>
      <h2>Classes</h2>
      <pre><code>{code}</code></pre>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Example of using `white-space` styling instead:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const code =
`
import React from 'react';

class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Classes</h1>
      <h2>Classes</h2>
      <code className="block">{code}</code>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I also included `display: block` because by default [`code`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) is inline.